# 403 Vertex AI API has not been used in project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Can anyone please help me with below error which I am getting while calling a Vertex AI service using Python.

```
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Vertex AI API has not been used in project my-project before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/aiplatform.googleapis.com/overview?project=my-project then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry. [links {
  description: "Google developers console API activation"
  url: "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/aiplatform.googleapis.com/overview?project=my-project"
```

Some important points,

1. In error message, my project name is mentioned as **my-project** however my actual project name is different.
2. I tried pointing to my project using **cloud config set project** command in python however still getting the same error.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Kapil Parmar, have you enabled all the [required API](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/apis/api/aiplatform.googleapis.com/metrics)'s of the vertex AI and other components if you are using any ?

Comment: You are using the phrase "Project Name". Google Cloud APIs use "Project ID" or "Project Number". Clarify your post so we know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. There was a simple miss from me.

In my python code there was a parameter for project id which had the default value as my-project. I updated this value to my actual project id post which the issue got resolved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Which service in Vertex AI you are using?  Also, what client did you initiate?  I got a 403 error stating I was using a different project while using the ChatVertexAI class even though I specified the correct project.  Switching it to VertexAIModelGarden fixed my problem.